# Better way of using arc4random

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, random, arc4random

I have a random method to create 2 random integers. My concern is that %65-%70 of outputs are same integers like "5-5" "4-4" "3-3".

```
-(void)random{
NSUInteger randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(5);

    switch (randomNumber) {
        case 0:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            break;

        case 1:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"];
            break;

        case 2:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"three.png"];
            break;

        case 3:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"four.png"];
            break;

        case 4:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"five.png"];
            break;
    }

    NSUInteger randomNumber2 = arc4random_uniform(5);

    switch (randomNumber2) {
        case 0:
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            break;

        case 1:
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"];
            break;

        case 2:
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"three.png"];
            break;

        case 3:
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"four.png"];
            break;

        case 4:
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"five.png"];
            break;
    }
}
```

Should i create 25 different case to reach better result?

```
NSUInteger randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(25);

   switch (randomNumber) {
        case 0:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            break;

        case 1:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"];
            break;

        case 2:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"three.png"];
            break;

        case 3:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"four.png"];
            break;

        case 4:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"five.png"];
            break;

        case 5:
            _tile2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"two.png"];
            _tile3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"one.png"];
            break;

        ...
    }
}
```

arc4random_uniform is great for getting one random integer. When i need to get 2 or more random numbers, the outputs are not that great. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Did you actually count the percentage of 'same integers' to be 65-70% in a large batch? It should be ±20%, using both methods.
Also note that you don't need to make 25 cases for the second method, you can extract the first number using `randomNumber/5` and second using `randomNumber%5` and then continue as in your first method.

Comment: @Aaganrmu yes i checked outputs for first random method with 1000 numbers. The result is like i said 65-70%. The aim of the second method is reduce the probability of getting same numbers. But when i need to get 3 or more random numbers, it will be disaster with this method.

Comment: I just ran the same test and only 20% were the same, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't believe you.  You must be doing something other than what you've shown.  The following code pasted into Playground consistently gives around a 20% match, not the 65-70% you claim:

```
import Cocoa

let sampleSize = 1000
var count = 0
for i in 1...sampleSize {
  var randomNumber1 = arc4random_uniform(5)
  var randomNumber2 = arc4random_uniform(5)
  if randomNumber1 == randomNumber2 {
    ++count
  }
}
println( Double(count) / Double(sampleSize) )
```

Whatever problem you're having, it isn't with how `arc4random_uniform` generates pairs of values.

Answer (score 0):

Would using an array of numbers be a solution for you? 
You can have a mutable array of numbers `[@0, @1, @2, @3, @4] and retrieve one number from a random index

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@0, @1, @2, @3, @4];
NSInteger firstIndex = arc4random_uniform([array count]);
NSNumber *firstNumber = array[index];
```

Remove the number you've just found:

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:firstIndex];
```

And than repeat the same for the second number. The first retrieved number won't be in the array anymore so even if the `arc4random_uniform()` gives you the same value (your 65-70% case) the actual number you are gonna use in your switch case it's gonna be different.

This approach is probably a bit clumsy, but I think it does what you need giving you a bit of control over the randomness.